# problems with testing and debugging datastore code in python using py.test

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am unit testing some `Python` `google cloud datastore` code using `py.test` in `PyCharm`. The code is running locally on `datastore emulator`.The problem is

1. I have to put multiple `time.sleep(num_secs)` after the code that does `put_multi()`, `put()` etc, and run the code under debug mode, going line by line to check the results so that `assert` wouldn't fail, since even if the code runs correctly, the result got back from the `emulator` using `query.fetch()` does not reflect the changes in the `datastore`. I realised that there might be a race condition happening between `Python` and `datastore simulator`. Hence a (big?) delay in making the changes effective?
2. Sometimes, even under debug mode and using `emulator`, I encountered `HTTP Error 404: Service Unavailable`. I then have to turn on the `Compute Engine` VMs, and so the code can be working again, even turn off the VMs afterwards. That is very strange. Note that it happened when the `App Engine` is already associated with the `project_id`.

I am wondering what is the best way to debug and test the `datastore` code in `Python`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For #1 the datastore emulator exacerbates the effects of [eventual consistency](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/structuring_for_strong_consistency#consistency_levels) for a certain fraction of the operations. From [gcloud beta emulators datastore start](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/emulators/datastore/start):

> `--consistency`=`CONSISTENCY`; default="0.9"
>
> ```
> Fraction of datastore operations that should succeed.
> ```

Comment: the `num_secs` set in `time.sleep()` is not consistent, sometimes it can be 1, 3, or even 10 and the unit testing can still fail due to the datastore haven't reflected the changes, so what is the best value can be set in `--consistency` flag?

Comment: `1`? But I'd question the validity of your tests - what is it that you're testing? In real life the code doing what what you're doing in these tests may fail as well. The code should be prepared to deal with eventual consistency, thus passing with 0.9 as well...

Comment: my code is using `datastore` to implement some basic database operations/methods, e.g. `add_row`, `update_row`, `delete_row`, etc. in `python`. The testing is just to validate these methods work by asserting the result meet the expected value. It just happens that the `datastore emulator` has some lag in reflecting the results of those operations. Hence, the testing could fail in that it doesn't get the desired result from the emulator.